# How to loop through file and echo each line with line number

Tags: linux, bash, unix, while-loop

How can I loop through a file, in bash, and echo the line and line number?

I have this, which has everything but the line number:

```
while read p;
do
echo "$p" "$LINE";
done < file.txt
```

Thanks for your help!

**edit** this will be run multi-thread using xargs, so i don't want to use a counter.

Comment: [nl(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nl)?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What *else* are you doing with `xargs`?

Comment: @nosid hmm, I didn't know about that. And to think I'm such a POSIX fiend, and should've known better than to use `cat -n`.

Answer (score 7):

I would just use `cat -n file`

But if you really want to use a bash loop:

```
i=0
while read; do
  printf '%d %s\n' $(( ++i )) "$REPLY"
done < file
```

Update: I now prefer `nl` to `cat -n`, as the former is standard. To get the same result as `cat -n`, use `nl -b a "$file"`.

Comment: cat -n will work! sorry i should have mentioned, I don't want to use a counter since this will be run on multiple instances and need unique counter for each line

Comment: @d-_-b use `nl -b a "$file"` – I didn't realize it, but cat -n is not POSIX and gains you nothing over `nl`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{print NR,$0}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '{print NR "\t" $0}' file.txt
```

Or you can keep a count of the line number in your loop:

```
count=0
while read line
do
    ((count+=1))
    printf "%5d:   %s\n" "$count" "$line"
done
```

Using `printf` allows you to format the number, so the lines in the file are all lined up.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, bash v4

```
mapfile lines < file.txt
for idx in "${!lines[@]}"; do printf "%5d %s" $((idx+1)) "${lines[idx]}"; done
```

Don't  do this.

Comment: Or for even more fun, `mapfile -c1 -O1 -C 'printf "%5d %s"' < file.txt`. Mapfile is weird.